# If DataBound Column Visibilty is False I cannot read Cell Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview element for listing members answers to my questionnaire. All the answers are stored as a string in one column. Each 4 digits are the answer of corresponding question. For a questionnaire which consists of 4 questions the answers could be `00010006000300040001`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" 
              runat="server"  
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="id, memberid, qid, qdate, member, membermail, qtitle, answer"
              OnSelectedIndexChanging="gv_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="memberid" HeaderText="Member ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="qid" HeaderText="Questionnaire ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="qdate" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="member" HeaderText="Member Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="membermail" HeaderText="Member E-mail" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="qtitle" HeaderText="Questionnaire" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="answer"  />
        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Analyze" ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Link" HeaderText="Analysis" />
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    string id         = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    string memberid   = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    string qid        = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
    string qdate      = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
    string memberName = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[4].Text;
    string memberMail = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[5].Text;
    string qtitle     = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[6].Text;
    string answer     = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[7].Text;

    //...
}
```

If I call answer cell's value of the selected rows when

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="answer" Visible="false" />
```

I cannot get answer and

```
 answer.Length //returns 0;
```

On the other hand, if `Visible="true"` everything is fine. But I do not want the answers to be listed in gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template field instead as below

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenFieldAnswer" Value='<%# Bind("answer") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you can  access the hidden field using the following code, in the selectedindex changed event

```
HiddenField  hiddenFieldAnswer = gv.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].FindControl("hiddenFieldAnswer") as HiddenField;
if (hiddenFieldAnswer != null)
{
    string answer = hiddenFieldAnswer.Value;
}
```

Comment: Could not it be solved using DataKeys or DataKeyNames? I was thinking that DataKeyNames attribute is for this kind of problems.

Comment: You can still use DataKeyNames to get the value (refer my answer). I agree with @Kiran Hegde 's answer too, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the value for `answer` as part of `DataKeyNames`, here is how you can get the respective value when you store multiple values in `DataKeyNames`.

```
protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    ....
    string answer= gv.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values["answer"].ToString();
    ...
}
```